# Using xcode 5 (iOS7sdk) to build non-iOS7 UI

Tags: audio, ios7, avaudiosession

Is it possible for me to use XCode 5 to build app with the old UI (non-iOS 7 style)?

My App required Audio Mic for input, when run in iOS 7, it has to ask permission for the Audio input to use.

```
if([[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] respondsToSelector:@selector(requestRecordPermission:)]){
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] requestRecordPermission:^(BOOL granted) {
        if (granted) {
            NSLog(@"Enabled Mic");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Disabled Mic");
        }
    }];
}
```

This API require iOS 7, So I need to use XCode 5 to build the app. The problem is I need to maintain the old UI look (e.g. black tabbar, buttons), which is reviewed by our client. Is it possible to do that using XCode 5 ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, you can't use Xcode 5 for non-iOS 7 development. Apple wan't us to redesign our apps for iOS 7 and any new app on the App Store will be rejected (I think).

Comment: The problem is that I have an existing app and I just want to do a simple bug fix, but now with Xcode 5 installed I either have to install Xcode 4 or redesign my app. Is that correct?

Comment: I think that you can't submit the app with Xcode 4 anymore. You need to redesign it. It will look awesome after a little job.

Comment: I don't think that's correct, Apple still accepts apps build with xcode 4. I uploaded one yesterday.

Comment: I'm not a expert but I think a read somewhere that apps must bee updated for iOS 7 and everybody knows that iOS 6 apps on iOS 7 do not look good at all.

Comment: Thankss for reply, I guess I left with no choice to use xcode 5 for that. :) but I still think old UI looks more pratical